# Running 2nd non-web java app process in Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, heroku-cli

I was wondering if it's possible to run a non-web java app in Heroku from within a web java app? Basically I want to execute a command to run the non-web app jar:

Calling something like this in Heroku for one off process:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar A.jar");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to execute the new process from the existing Java process. Instead, you should create a new process type in your app's `Procfile`, like this:

```
web: java -jar webapp-runner.jar yourapp.war
worker: java -jar A.jar
```

Then you can run the worker process from the CLI `heroku run worker`, or you can make an HTTP call to the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference).

I assume you are using `heroku war:deploy`, which means you probably don't have a `Procfile` at this time. You may need to switch to `heroku jar:deploy` and [include webapp-runner in your app manually](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner).

Comment: Do you know if are you able to pass arguments to the work? Like passing arguments when executing a jar in command line?

Comment: You can run `heroku run "java -jar A.jar --option one"` if you want a custom command.